# JQuery + css elements not aligned

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code for a popup:

CSS:

```
#mypopup-popup{
  right: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 12%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="mypopup">
  <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a" align="right">
      <p><label for="Smoke">Smoke Sensor:</label></p>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" align="left">
      <p><select name='U' id='U' data-role='slider' data-mini='true' data-theme='a'/>
      <option value='off'>Off</option>
      <option value='on'>On</option>
      </select></p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

But I cannot seem to align text Smoke Sensor: with the slider, the text appears slightly upper than the slider

[image]

And also, if i want to add more text + sliders to bottom of that one, how can i do it ?

Comment: Where do you close `<fieldset>`?

Comment: You appear to me to be aligned correctly given the code you have.  You  probably just need to add a left margin to the slider and use `line-height` or `position:relative` to position the text so it's more vertically centered relative to the slider.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle, please. You can edit thisone. http://jsfiddle.net/DfEu9/ (i've closed the <fieldset> tag).

Comment: @celerno that jsfiddle you gave, shows a 'Smoke sensor' text in the right and the slider on the left, but both on different lines, totally not what I want.


@ RangingCelt how can i add that left margin to the slider ?

Comment: @Carlcox89 I made the jsfiddle using your code; it requires more libraries/code you'll need to add (here or there) so we can help better.